# How to set up a logic table of exception handling cleanly?

Tags: java, functional-programming, refactoring

I’m looking for a clean and perhaps functional way to structure my code describing a logic table of exception handling.

```
| oldSave result | newSave result | action           |
|----------------|----------------|------------------|
| success        | success        | -                |
| failure        | failure        | `doSomething1()` |
| failure        | success        | `doSomething2()` |
| success        | failure        | `doSomething3()` |
```

Here is a small toy example of my solution to achieve this, by catching the errors and returning them in the `joinFuture()` function. I use a null result to describe the case where the future call is successful.

```java
public void save(Dog object) {
    # clients support the save() method
    Future oldSave = executorService.submit(() -> oldClient.save(object));
    Future newSave = executorService.submit(() -> newClient.save(object));

    RuntimeException oldWriteException = joinFuture(oldSave);
    RuntimeException newWriteException = joinFuture(newSave);

    if (isSuccessful(oldWriteException) && isSuccessful(newWriteException)) {
        return;
    }

    if (!isSuccessful(oldWriteException) && !isSuccessful(newWriteException)) {
        doSomething1(object, oldWriteException, newWriteException);
        return;
    }

    if (isSuccessful(newWrite)) {
        doSomething2(object, oldWriteException, newWriteException);
        return;
    }

    // new write failed
    doSomething3(object, oldWriteException, newWriteException);
}

private boolean isSuccessful(RuntimeException exception) {
    return exception == null;
}

private RuntimeException joinFuture(Future future) {
    try {
        future.get();
        return null;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return new RuntimeException("Failed to retrieve data from future: " + e.getCause());
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        return RuntimeException(e.getCause());
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        return e;
    }
}
```

I toyed with the idea of placing the result of `joinFuture()` into a `Optional<RuntimeException>`, but it felt weird and did not add much value to the code here. Is there another approach I can use to do this?

Comment: return an `enum SaveResult { SUCCESS, BOTH_FAIL, OLD_FAIL, NEW FAIL  }` ?

Comment: @Michael I've actually considered that as well, but just trying to explore more elegant / functional ways to do this (if any) :)

Answer (score 0):

I did not code java for a while, so i can just put you in the right direction for now.

I think you can approach it like this:

Use a Map that maps a Boolean(success/failure) to another Map which maps again a Boolean (success/failure) to a Method-Reference.

```
Map<Boolean, Map<Boolean, Function>> config = new Map ...
```

Put your configuration table into that map.

Then look up the action you want to execute with the results of isSuccessful(oldWriteException) und isSuccessful(newWriteException).

Then execute that action.

Maybe you also find this helpful, because you will need i TriFunction Interface i guess:

https://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/method-references-in-java-8